# How to perform an unregularized logistic regression using scikit-learn?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, regularized

From scikit-learn's [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), the default penalty is "l2", and C (inverse of regularization strength) is "1". If I keep this setting penalty='l2' and C=1.0, does it mean the training algorithm is an unregularized logistic regression? In contrast, when C is anything other than 1.0, then it's a regularized logistic regression classifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not like that.

Let's have a look at the definitions within [sklearn's user-guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression):

[image]

#### We see:

- `C` is multiplied with the loss while the left-term (regularization) is untouched

#### This means:

- Without modifying the code you can never switch-off the regularization completely
- **But:** you can approximately switch-off regularization by setting `C` to a huge number!

  - As the optimization tries to minimize the sum of regularization-penalty and loss, increasing `C` decreases the relevance of the regularization-penalty

Answer (score 0):

first, set `C` to a large value (relative to your expected coefficients).

If it does not work for you, also set `penalty='l1'`